# Sorting predicates in PROLOG

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have some predicates

```
p1( 301, 1, 2 ).
p2( 201, 5, 2 ).
p3( 501, 1, 5 ).
p4( 401, 1, 4 ).
```

I want to sort them in numerical order depending on the 3rd clause(Ascending order), if they have the same value I sort them depending on the 2nd clause(descending order)

```
p2( 201, 5, 2 ).
p1( 301, 1, 2 ).
p4( 401, 1, 4 ).
p3( 501, 1, 5 ).
```

I am new to prolog, is there any function to sort predicates ?

Comment: `predsort` is at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=predsort/3 (click on the orange circle in top-right, to see the source code).

Answer (score 0):

Using https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=order_by/2

```
p(301, 1, 2).
p(201, 5, 2).
p(501, 1, 5).
p(401, 1, 4).

test_sort :-
    forall(
        order_by([asc(C), desc(B)],
            p(A, B, C)
        ),
        assertz(p_sorted(A, B, C))
    ).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- listing(p_sorted).
:- dynamic p_sorted/3.

p_sorted(201, 5, 2).
p_sorted(301, 1, 2).
p_sorted(401, 1, 4).
p_sorted(501, 1, 5).
```

Answer (score -1):

```
d(p2, 201, 5, 2 ).
d(p1, 301, 1, 2 ).
d(p4, 401, 1, 4 ).
d(p3, 501, 1, 5 ).
sortpred(A,B,C):- ..... A='<' .... A='>' ... A='='.
:- findall(d(A,B,C,D),d(A,B,C,D),Ls),
predsort(sortpred,Ls,Rs), writeln(Rs).
:- halt.
```

If you want to create a sort predicate, look at the following:

URLhttps://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/~prabhas//teaching/dsys/2004/quick-prolog.htm